# Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 newline conversion on Windows---is the documentation misleading?

Tags: haskell

I have a question about the Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 library in the bytestring library. Specifically, my question concerns the readFile function, which is documented as follows:

> Read an entire file lazily into a ByteString. Use 'text mode' on Windows to interpret newlines

I'm interested in the claim that this function will 'use text mode on Windows to interpret newlines'. The source code for the function is as follows:

```
-- | Read an entire file /lazily/ into a 'ByteString'. Use 'text mode'
-- on Windows to interpret newlines
readFile :: FilePath -> IO ByteString
readFile f = openFile f ReadMode >>= hGetContents
```

and we see that, in one sense, the claim in the documentation is perfectly true: the `openFile` function (as opposed to `openBinaryFile`) has been used, and so newline conversion will be enabled for the file.

*But*, the file will then be passed to hGetContents. This will call `Data.ByteString.hGetNonBlocking` (see the source code [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.1.5/doc/html/src/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#hGetContents) and [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.1.5/doc/html/src/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#hGetContentsN)), which is meant to be a non blocking version of `Data.ByteString.hGet` (see [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.1.7/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#v%3ahGetNonBlocking)); and (finally) `Data.ByteString.hGet` calls `GHC.IO.Handle.hGetBuf` (see [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.1.7/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#v%3ahGet) or [the source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/0.9.1.7/doc/html/src/Data-ByteString.html#hGet)). This function's [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.2/doc/html/GHC-IO-Handle.html#v%3ahGetBuf) says that

> hGetBuf ignores whatever TextEncoding the Handle is currently using, and reads bytes directly from the underlying IO device.

which suggests that the fact that we opened the file using `readFile` rather than `readBinaryFile` is irrelevant: the data will be read without transforming newlines, notwithstanding the claim in the documentation referred to at the beginning of the question.

So, the nub of the question:
1. Am I missing something? Is there some sense in which the statement 'that Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.readFile uses text mode on Windows to interpret newlines' is true? Or is the documentation just misleading?

P.S. Testing also indicates that this function, at least when used naively as I was using it, does no newline conversion on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, the package maintainer, Duncan Coutts, responded with some very helpful and enlightening remarks. I've asked for his permission to post them here, but in the interim here is a paraphrase.

The basic point is that the documentation was once correct, but now probably is not. In particular, when one opens a file in windows, the operating system itself lets you open it in 'text' or 'binary' modes. The difference between `readFile` and `readBinaryFile` *used* to be that one would open the file in the OS's text mode and one in binary mode on Win32. (They would both do the same on POSIX.) Critically, if you opened a file in the OS's binary mode, there was *no way* you could read from the file without newline conversion: it happened *always*.

When things were set up like this, the documentation referred to in the question was correct---`Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.readFile` would use `System.IO.readFile`; this would tell the OS to open the file 'Text', and newlines would be converted, even though `hGetBuf` was being used.

Then, later, Haskell's `System.IO` was souped up to make its handling of newlines more flexible---specifically to allow versions of Haskell running on POSIX OSs, where there is no functionality to read files with newline mangling built into the OS, nonetheless to support reading files with Windows style newlines; or more accurately to support Python-style ['universal' newline conversion](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) on both OSs. This meant that:

1. The handling of newlines was brought into the Haskell libraries;
2. Files are *always* opened in binary mode on Windows, whether you use `readFile` or `readBinaryFile`; and
3. Instead, the choice between `readFile` and `readBinaryFile` would affect whether `System.IO`'s library code was set up to be in `nativeNewlineMode` or `noNewlineTranslation`. This would then cause the Haskell library conversion to do appropriate newline conversion for you. You could now also choose to ask for `universalNewlineMode`.

This was at about the same time as Haskell got proper encoding support built in to `System.IO` (rather than assuming latin-1 on input and simply truncating output Chars to their first 8 bits). Overall, it was a Good Thing.

But, critically, the new newline conversion, now built in to the libraries, *never affects what `hPutBuf` does*---presumably because the people building the new `System.IO` functionality thought that if one was reading the fine in a binary way, any newline conversion interposing itself was probably *not* What the Programmer Wanted, i.e. was a mistake. And indeed, it probably is in 99% of cases: but in this case, it causes the problem above :-)

Duncan says that the docs will probably change to reflect this brave new world in future releases of the library. In the interim, [there is a workaround listed in another answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6860159/194894)

Answer (score 2):

Digging one more layer into the source shows it does read raw bytes:

```
-- | 'hGetBuf' @hdl buf count@ reads data from the handle @hdl@
-- into the buffer @buf@ until either EOF is reached or
-- @count@ 8-bit bytes have been read.
-- It returns the number of bytes actually read.  This may be zero if
-- EOF was reached before any data was read (or if @count@ is zero).
--
-- 'hGetBuf' never raises an EOF exception, instead it returns a value
-- smaller than @count@.
--
-- If the handle is a pipe or socket, and the writing end
-- is closed, 'hGetBuf' will behave as if EOF was reached.
--
-- 'hGetBuf' ignores the prevailing 'TextEncoding' and 'NewlineMode'
-- on the 'Handle', and reads bytes directly.

hGetBuf :: Handle -> Ptr a -> Int -> IO Int
hGetBuf h ptr count
  | count == 0 = return 0
  | count <  0 = illegalBufferSize h "hGetBuf" count
  | otherwise = 
      wantReadableHandle_ "hGetBuf" h $ \ h_@Handle__{..} -> do
         flushCharReadBuffer h_
         buf@Buffer{ bufRaw=raw, bufR=w, bufL=r, bufSize=sz }
            <- readIORef haByteBuffer
         if isEmptyBuffer buf
            then bufReadEmpty    h_ buf (castPtr ptr) 0 count
            else bufReadNonEmpty h_ buf (castPtr ptr) 0 count
```

Comment: Reasonable link to git for Text.hs is at: http://git.megacz.com/?p=ghc-base.git;a=tree;f=GHC/IO/Handle;hb=HEAD

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that the code was reading raw bytes! (Although I was 99% sure after my digging :-) ) Do you think that this is definitely a documentation error, or does setting text mode have some other purpose that I don't know about and which isn't totally frustrated by the use of hGetBuf? If it is a documentation bug, do you know what the procedures are for submitting a patch to change the docstrings in Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8?

Comment: It sounds like a documentation error for readFile in the bytestring package. Two maintainers (with e-mail addresses) are listed at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring and they can help get that fixed.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I will email the maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer to the question as asked, but I thought I would mention the following workaround for the benefit of others who hit this problem and find this page on Stack Overflow.  It uses the stringsearch package.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Search as S
import qualified System.IO
import Control.Monad

nativeCallsForConversion        = System.IO.nativeNewline == System.IO.CRLF
readFileUniversalNewlineConversion = let
  str_LF   = B.pack [10]
  str_CRLF = B.pack [13, 10]
  in liftM (S.replace str_CRLF str_LF) . L.readFile
readFileNativeNewlineConversion =
  if nativeCallsForConversion
  then readFileUniversalNewlineConversion
  else L.readFile
```