# Data.ByteString output not correct

Tags: haskell, text, io, bytestring

I'm writing a program which would take a list of text files as arguments and outputs a file in which each row is the intercalation of tabs between the corresponding rows in the files.

**Assume all characters are ASCII encoded**

```
import GHC.IO.Handle
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Data.List

main = do
    (out:files) <- getArgs
    hs <- mapM (`openFile` ReadMode) files
    txts <- mapM B.hGetContents hs
    let final = map (B.intercalate (B.singleton '\t')) . transpose 
                . map (B.lines . B.filter (/= '\t')) $ txts
    withFile out WriteMode $ \out -> 
        B.hPutStr out (B.unlines final)
    putStrLn "Completed successfully"
```

The problem is that it outputs:

```
file1row1
    file2row1
file1row2
    file2row2
file1row3
    file2row3
```

instead of:

```
file1row1    file2row1
file1row2    file2row2
file1row3    file2row3
```

The same logic works correctly when tested by manually defining the functions in ghci. And the same code works correctly when using `Data.Text.Lazy` instead of lazy `Bytestring`s.

What's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug in Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8 where newline conversion doesn't take place properly, even though the documentation says that it should. (See [Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 newline conversion on Windows---is the documentation misleading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837628/data-bytestring-lazy-char8-newline-conversion-on-windows-is-the-documentation)) This could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I'm using `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` not `UTF8`. Could you elaborate more on the problem, I don't seem to understand what's going on.

Comment: Newline characters are all ASCII characters and should work just fine when read as single bytes.

Comment: Ok, I took a look at your workaround in the other question and I kind of got an idea of what's happening. Isn't it very weird that there's no solution till now for this problem?

Comment: Yes, it really has been a while since the maintainer promised a fix 'real soon now' (see the answer in the other question). I guess the workaround is not too tricky though. The biggest issue (at least for me) is that this behavior is such a surprise... if there was a warning in the docs, it would be better!

Answer (score 2):

When I tested Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8.lines on a sample string, it didn't remove the '\r'....

```
ghci -XOverloadedStrings

> import Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8 as B

> B.lines "ab\n\rcd"
  ["ab","\rcd"]

> B.lines "ab\r\ncd"
  ["ab\r","cd"]
```

I am guessing this is your problem.

(to verify, you can look at the output using "xxd" or any other hex editor....  See if the extra character is in fact a "\r").